steam installs on 22.04 and 24.04 has large time delay with keyboard
I am having issues with keyboard input with steam. I have 2 computers both dell optiplex 7020. the first computer is working fine and no problems with steam. Steam was loaded into
ubuntu 20.04 and since upgraded to 22.04 to 24.04 still no problems with steam. The second
computer was loaded with ubuntu 22.04 install. steam was loaded with no errors but when trying to run games there is a 1/2 to 1 second delay from the keyboard. I tried different keyboards, moving the usb ports, and uninstalling and reinstalling steam + games. No improvement. I quit trying.... When 24.04 came out I upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04. Steam still had issues with keyboard. This time I reformated the hard drive and loaded 24.04 directly
no upgrading. steam still has time delay problem with keyboard.anybody know how to remedy this problem?

Is there NVidia graphics on the problematic laptop? If so, does it help if you switch the graphics driver?

Have you tried with a different Proton version? You can select a specific Proton version for any games. If I remember its in the game's properties.

not a laptop it's a desktop work station. here is the graphics card info

Can you elaborate about proton version? I don't remember there being any options when I set up my steam account on the first computer. I am still learning my way around linux, I know enough to get myself in trouble.

Is your cursor delayed as well? Reason I ask is I've had an issue similar, Mine was due to driver issue. the games were trying to run on my iGpu instead of my dedicated Gpu in my laptop. And which version of steam are you currently running, And is it snap or flatpak? if one or the other you could try the opposite version.
I would run the fps overlay in steam to see if otherwise it appears to be performing as expected.
Update system and drivers

No my cursor isn't affected. However I should try removing steam and try a flatpak install. I know playing in the sandbox sometimes causes headaches. I'll have to give it a try.

uninstalled steam snap, reloaded steam with flatpack. Still has unusable time delay from keyboard. :(
